# How to change the size of an array from another class in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm Struggling with a bit of GUI design in java, I want to change the size of a 2D array of Jbuttons from another class. Changing the size, will change the amount of buttons added on the frame. I tried doing it with instance variables and get() methods, however, it doesn't seem to be working on the array of buttons.
I've given only the relevant code below:

```
public class Minefield extends JFrame{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private int ROWS;
    private int COLS;
    private JButton[][] grid = new JButton[getRows()][getCols()];

    public Minefield(int rows, int cols){
        super("Minesweeper 1");

        setRows(rows);
        setCols(cols);

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
                grid[i][j] = new JButton("[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
                panel.add(grid[i][j]);
                grid[i][j].addActionListener(handler);
            }
            container.add(panel);
        }
    }

    public void setRows(int rows){
        ROWS = rows;
    }

    public int getRows(){
        return ROWS;
    }

    public void setCols(int cols){
        COLS = cols;
    }

    public int getCols(){
        return COLS;
    }
}
```

Then here's the tester class I'd like to run the GUI from, in which I can't figure out how to change the array

```
public class MinefieldTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Minefield minefield = new Minefield(4,2);
        minefield.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the size of array after it got created?
If so do you want to preserve the existing data?

Comment: The initializer for `grid` runs *before* the body of the `Minefield` constructor, so `ROWS` and `COLS` are both 0 when `getRows()` and `getCols()` are called, which means you get `new JButton[0][0]` and your `for` loops do nothing. Also, setting `ROWS` and `COLS` in the setter methods *after* the constructor completes, will not magically re-size the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`grid` field initialize before you set the `row` and `column`.

**change this**

```
private JButton[][] grid = new JButton[getRows()][getCols()];

public Minefield(int rows, int cols){
    super("Minesweeper 1");

    setRows(rows);
    setCols(cols);

    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
            grid[i][j] = new JButton("[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            panel.add(grid[i][j]);
            grid[i][j].addActionListener(handler);
        }
        container.add(panel);
    }
}
```

**to:**

```
private JButton[][] grid;

public Minefield(int rows, int cols){
    super("Minesweeper 1");

    setRows(rows);
    setCols(cols);

    grid = new JButton[getRows()][getCols()];


    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
            grid[i][j] = new JButton("[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            panel.add(grid[i][j]);
            grid[i][j].addActionListener(handler);
        }
        container.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit obscure in what you hope to achieve, however, you could not be initialising the array during the classes initialising phase (which is run before the constructor), but rather in the constructor.

This means that the values for `rows` and `cols` will be set BEFORE you initialise the array itself.

The following demonstrates a possible workflow which would allow you to change the size of the array (and thus the number of buttons) even after the class is constructed, making it dynamic

```
public class Minefield extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private JButton[][] grid;

    public Minefield(int rows, int cols) {
        super("Minesweeper 1");

        setGridSize(cols, rows);
    }

    public void setGridSize(int cols, int rows) {
        container.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = new JButton("[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
                panel.add(grid[i][j]);
                grid[i][j].addActionListener(handler);
            }
            container.add(panel);
        }
        container.revalidate();
        container.repaint();
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getCols() {
        return cols;
    }
}
```

There is little point in having the setters for the `rows` and `cols`, as it makes it very difficult to re-construct the array, if you want to provide the ability to change the array AFTER the class is created, then using `setGridSize` and passing both parameters in at once will make it much easier to update.  Otherwise, you should probably just forego them and only pass them to the constructor